# Trouble with Python(x,y) installation that creates a C:\Anaconda2 directory

Tags: python, anaconda, pythonxy

I'm trying to reinstall a Python(x,y) distribution on my computer. Before that, I had a Anaconda2 distribution and a WinPython distribution which I have uninstalled correctly (and removed system paths).

I'm doing the custom installation of Python(x,y) to specify the Python path directory. The problem is that after the installation, if I check in the Python directory, I don't have all the packages that are supposed to be installed with PythonXY: they are all located in a C:\Anaconda2 directory. Therefore, nothing can start (Spyder or others).

Why is it doing that ? Are all the packages not supposed to be in the C:\Python27_XY directory that I specified during the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Anaconda didn't clean the registry, so all modules were still registered. I did a search for "anaconda" in the registry and deleted all occurences. Now the Python(x,y) installation went well.